# Matrix second derivate

Tags: matrices, derivatives

How to calculate the derivative of
$$
\operatorname{Tr}\left(\left(Y \circ (FF^T)\right)FF^T\right)
$$
(where the symbol "$\circ$" means Hadamard/elementwise product) with respect to $F$?

Thanks.

Comment: $\odot$ is element-wise product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, define 2 matrix variables $$\eqalign{X&=FF^T\,\,\,=X^T\cr Z&=2(Y+Y^T)}$$ Also, let's use the inner/Frobenius product notation instead of the trace, e.g. $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Now we can write the function and find its differential & gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\lambda
 &= Y\odot X:X \cr
 &= Y:X\odot X \cr\cr
d\lambda
 &= Y:2X\odot dX \cr
 &= 2Y\odot X:dX \cr
 &= 2Y\odot X:(dF\,F^T+F\,dF^T) \cr
 &= Z\odot X:dF\,F^T \cr
 &= (Z\odot X)F:dF \cr\cr
G = \frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial F}
 &= (Z\odot X)F \cr
 &= \Big(2(Y+Y^T)\odot (FF^T)\Big)F \cr\cr
}$$
So that's the gradient.  If you want the gradient of the gradient (i.e. the hessian) start by finding the differential of $G$
$$\eqalign{
dG &= (Z\odot dX)F + (Z\odot X)\,dF \cr
}$$
This will lead to a 4th order tensor which you will find difficult to use. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you show more details in $2Y \odot X : (dFF^T + FdF^T) = Z \odot X :dFF^T$ and what is the relationships between $dF$ and $dF^T$. Thanks so much.

Comment: $$\eqalign{d\lambda &= 2Y\odot X:(dF\,F^T+F\,dF^T)\cr&= 2Y\odot X:dF\,F^T+ 2Y\odot X:F\,dF^T\cr&= 2Y\odot X:dF\,F^T+ 2(Y\odot X)^T:(F\,dF^T)^T\cr&= 2Y\odot X:dF\,F^T+ 2Y^T\odot X:dF\,F^T\cr&= 2(Y+Y^T)\odot X:dF\,F^T\cr&= Z\odot X:dF\,F^T}$$